# using django transactions how to handle IntegrityError when commit happens

Tags: django, transactions

I want to handle properly an IntegrityError exception can be raised when a transaction is commited, and at first glance i see two alternatives to implement that, but not sure if both are correct, Can somebody clarify if both are right or not, and why?

**Note**: I'm using PostgreSQL

```
# alternative one
try:
  with transaction.commit_on_success():
    # db operation 1
    # db operation 2
except IntegrityError:
    transaction.rollback()

#alternative two
with transaction.commit_manually():
  sid = transaction.savepoint()
  # db operation 1
  # db operation 2
  try:
    transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
  except IntegrityError:
    transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
```

Comment: If commit_on_success() fails, you do not need a rollback()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event of an IntegrityError, use transaction.rollback() to roll back the entire transaction. If you only want to roll back parts of the transaction use transaction.savepoint(). If you only have one savepoint for the entire transaction, it will have the same effect as transaction.rollback().

Comment: just wonder if the use of transaction.rollback out of scope of with's context is well used, because my intention is rollback just operation 1 & 2, nothing else before that segment of code

Comment: I would go for the savepoint in this case. That gives you full control over what you are rolling back.

Comment: This seems interesting as well: http://thebuild.com/blog/2012/03/19/a-recipe-for-django-transactions-on-postgresql/